# Javascript Change Class Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the following code that, when you click on the link the whole style will be changed.

```js
$(".buybuttons").click(function() {
  $(".buybuttons").removeClass().addClass('buybuttonsclick');
});
```

```css
.buybuttons {
  background-color:#000000;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}

.buybuttonsclick {
  background-color:#ff0000;
  text-align:right;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="buybuttons">Click To Change</a>
```

The question is, how can I put a reverse on it?!

I mean when I click again, it changes to the first style (buybuttons).

Comment: The `click` handler assigns itself to `.buybuttons` at the time your code runs.  If you remove the class, the assignment is still there.  Add a `console.log` inside your handler and you'll see the code runs when you click it a second time even though the class has been removed.  If you *don't* want this behaviour, then use event delegation.

Comment: You can use `toggleClass` for that. For more detail go through mention link [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `toggleClass()`?

```js
$(".buybuttons").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('buybuttonsclick');
});
```

```css
.buybuttons {
  background-color:#000000;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}

.buybuttonsclick {
  background-color:#ff0000;
  text-align:right;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="buybuttons">Click To Change</a>
```

Comment: @guradio There's no need to toggle `buybuttons` class aswell, because anyways it's being overwritten with `buybuttonsclick` class. However, it wouldn't work properly if we would swap classes positions.

Comment: you are correct i didnt know style will be overriden when added another i didnt know about the priority on which class the style will be used.

Answer (score 2):

1. Because when you remove the class your click event is not happening.
2. Add another class on the anchor then use it in click event.
3. Use toggleClass()

```js
$(".anchorclass").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('buybuttonsclick buybuttons');
});
```

```css
.buybuttons {
  background-color:#000000;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}

.buybuttonsclick {
  background-color:#ff0000;
  text-align:right;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="buybuttons anchorclass">Click To Change</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `toggleClass()` function, It `add` or `remove` one or more `classes` from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument. You can find the documention [JQuery toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
$(".buybuttons").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('buybuttonsclick');
});
```

```css
.buybuttons {
  background-color:#000000;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}

.buybuttonsclick {
  background-color:#ff0000;
  text-align:right;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="buybuttons">Click To Change</a>
```

```
$(".buybuttons").click(function() {
   $(".buybuttons").toggleClass('buybuttonsclick');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you change class twice then use `toggelclass`

```js
$(".buybuttons").click(function() {
  $(".buybuttons").toggleClass('buybuttonsclick');
});
```

```css
.buybuttons {
  background-color:#000000;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}

.buybuttonsclick {
  background-color:#ff0000;
  text-align:right;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="buybuttons">Click To Change</a>
```

Comment: ya bro but that time i solve question before i answer , answer already there @guradio

Answer (score 0):

You can opt for `toggleClass()` instead of removing and adding classes. Just a little change..

```
$(".buybuttons").click(function() {
   $(".buybuttons").toggleClass('buybuttonsclick');
});
```

Anyways I hope you got your answer. Bit late to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want always keep any class

```
$(".buybuttons, .buybuttonsclick").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('buybuttonsclick');
  $(this).toggleClass('buybuttons');
});
```